# Route is not found in express. How to add routers dynamically?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I try to add dynamically the routes but when I send a post request in with postman it return not found, and I can see in the app a 404 logged next to the endpoint.
SO I assume that the endpoint is not found but I know that I added the router dynamically, so why does express not see it? How can I make it work? Where am I doing wrong I can't see.
here the server.js:

```
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
 
var server = http.createServer(app);
 
server.listen(port, onListening); 

function onListening() {
  var addr = server.address();
  var bind = typeof addr === 'string' ? 'pipe ' + addr : 'port ' + addr.port;
  debug('Listening on ' + bind);
  console.log(`\x1b[33mServer listening on port ${port}`);
}
```

Here where I app.js:

```
import celebrate from 'celebrate';
import cookieParser from 'cookie-parser';
import cors from 'cors';
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
import express from 'express';
import createError from 'http-errors';
import logger from 'morgan';
import path from 'path';

import MountRouters from './utils/MountRouter';

dotenv.config();

const app = express();

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json({ limit: '2GB' }));
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false, limit: '50mb' }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'build')));

// create all the routers
(async () => {
  await MountRouters(app);
})();

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'build', 'index.html'));
});

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  next(createError(404));
});

app.use(celebrate.errors());

// error handler
app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.send(err.message);
});

module.exports = app;
```

Here it is the MountRouters.js:

```
import { readdir } from 'fs/promises';
import path from 'path';
 
async function GetSubdirectories(dir) {
  return (await readdir(dir, { withFileTypes: true })).filter(dirent => dirent.isDirectory());
}
 
async function MountRouters(app) {
  const dirs = await GetSubdirectories(path.join(__dirname, '../routes'));

  for (const dirent of dirs) {
    const { name } = dirent;
    const routerModule = path.join(name, 'router');
    try {
      const router = (await import(`../routes/${routerModule}`)).default;

      if (router) {
        console.log(`Mounting route: "/api/v1/${name}"`);
        app.use(`/api/v1/${name}`, router);
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.log('ERROR mounting...', err);
      console.info(`No route defined for module "${name}"`);
    }
  }

  return app;
}

export default MountRouters;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because your `MountRouters()` function is async, but you mount all the other routes synchronously, your dynamic routes actually get mounted last. This puts them after your 404 handler, which will then receive the requests before they do, and return a 404 response.

To address that, you can mount your other routes inside of the IIFE too:

```js
...
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'build')));

// create all the routers
(async () => {
  await MountRouters(app);

  app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'build', 'index.html'));
  });

  // catch 404 and forward to error handler
  app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    next(createError(404));
  });

  app.use(celebrate.errors());

  // error handler
  app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
    // set locals, only providing error in development
    res.locals.message = err.message;
    res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

    // render the error page
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.send(err.message);
  });
})();

module.exports = app;
```

Comment: thank you@Aurast for your time and answer! I thought that if I put the MounRouters in a IIFE it would make it syncronous, but it was still asyncronous.

Comment: Glad I could help. There is no way to make an async operation synchronous in JavaScript.